# 3 Boxes on each row, 2nd row doesnt align. JS fiddle

Tags: html, css

I have two rows of 3 boxes, boxes, include image, heading and text. The second row doesn't align. I have set up a JS Fiddle for this to show you my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/2QJhN/

What is the issue? What have I missed out/done wrong or both?

Comment: Google Chrome. But it doesn't work on any browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floats can be strange when you put them in multiple rows. One solution is to add a hidden div after each column to sort them out. The usual convention is to give it the class name "clear", with this CSS:

```
.clear
{
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2QJhN/3/

**EDIT:** Please note there are lots of different ways to solve this issue, you can wrap each row in a DIV with some other CSS, which some people prefer and may consider neater. In your case it's still an extra DIV though.

You'd give it the classname "clearfix":

```
.clearfix:after, .windowContent:after, .pane:after          
{
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
```

}

```
* html .clearfix , * html .windowContent , * html .pane
{
    zoom: 1;
}
*:first-child+html .clearfix , *:first-child+html .windowContent, *:first-child+html    .pane
{
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: this is a workaround.. but i would like to know why what is happening is happening  -- the problem??

Comment: What was causing the problem then? So i know for the future

Comment: Hard to say, my guess is that when the divs can be varying heights (due to text), they are more prone to this problem. If you simply had images all the same height, then it shouldn't happen. Your margins in any of those divs might also be interfering. Sorry I don't have a solid answer for you, I'm sure there are plenty of articles out there that explain it well.

Comment: You could also just set a fixed height for the `col` class.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. Of course the issue with that is if one of the boxes needed lots of text.

Answer (score 1):

you put this code after the first row.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DSGCv/1/